# grails sum one-to-many

Tags: grails, sum, grails-orm

I need a help with what I believe is very trivial stuff.

```
class User {
    String name 
    static hasMany = [files : File]
}

class File {
    long size
}
```

Now when I need the total size of all files a given user has I use the following which is working :

```
def user = User.get(id)
user.files.each(total+=it.size)
```

but how ugly is it, when I am sure it can be done with simple select sum query with either plain SQL or GORM/CRITERIA

I have tried something like File.sumBySize..()

Or

```
def c = File.createCriteria()
def f = c.list{
    eq("user",  user)   // What here ?
    projections
        {
        sum("size")
        }
    }
```

I dont know how to specify the parent(user) relationship which is not defined in File class but in Grails join tables

Any help appreciated

Comment: Why is that ugly?  I would just put that code in a convenience method right in the User domain.  Then just call userInstance.totalFileSize()

Comment: I don't know. I just feel this should be done by query rather then looping trough collection. And I am curious how to make this work other ways too. I fail to do this by criteria.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with an HQL query, but it has a small problem with the name of the 'size' field 
(appears to be a reserved word). If you rename it to 'length', 'fileSize', etc. then this will work:

```
User.executeQuery(
   'select sum(file.length) from User u join u.files file where u.id=:userId',
   [userId: id])[0]
```

Comment: ... but that seems more complicated than your original code, LOL.

Comment: ..I know right :D But I just wanted to see other options. Besides.. what is really happening behind Gorm->hibernate-> ? In the end it is still sql right ? I wonder what gives better performance, less operations above DB etc..

Comment: For this somewhat contrived example, doing it the original way wouldn't be that bad. But in a real app the File class will most likely have other fields, so a direct query that gets just the data you need is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Why is that ugly?  It only takes 1 statement (with no SQL at all) to sum up all the file sizes.  Though if you want, you *may* be able to use HQL like so:

```
def user = User.get(id)
def sum = File.executeQuery("select sum(f.size) from File f where f.user = ?", user);
```

But I think you'd need to add a belongsTo to File to do that.  There's probably a simpler HQL/GORM method that's just not coming to my mind at the moment, but honestly, I don't think there's anything easier than what you already did.

Comment: Yes, this works only when I add belongsTo = [user: User]. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant way to sum the file sizes in Groovy code is:

```
def total = user.files.sum {it.size}
```

But if you can calculate the file size totals in the query that returns the users, that's the way I'd do it.